# Advice on a report

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, cron

I have to create a report that is automatically compiled monthly. The report just needs to be the unique count of phone numbers across 2 apps (Rails apps, call them app A and B). Each app has a PostgreSQL database and the phone numbers are columns in a table. Getting the unique phone number count in each app is easy, it's just a 'SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT phone_number)...' query. However, I can't come up with a simple/efficient way to do it across both apps (Also, app A has 500k records in the table and app B has 8k). It seems I'll have to pull out all phone numbers from both tables, put them together and toss out duplicates. The problem is it's too many records to deal with in memory.

Anyone have advice on the best way to do this? Here's some additional info:

- Both apps are on the same server
- The database server is also on this server
- The apps are on different databases
- Generating/emailing the report will be a cron job
- I'd prefer to do most of the programming in ruby, preferably in one of the apps

Answer (score 1):

SQL has a UNION method that might be what your looking for... In the database, you would be able to pull DISTINCT values from a UNION between your 2 queries.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (phone_number) 
FROM
    ( <subquery1>
      UNION ALL
      <subquery2>
    );
```

That would give you a very efficient SQL query. Now, if you want to implement this from a Rails perspective, getting the results from both queries, then performing a unique validation would be best.

```
results1 = Table1.select('DISTINCT phone_number')
results2 = Table2.select('DISTINCT phone_number')

results = (results1 + results2).uniq!
```

Hope that's what you were looking for!

Comment: The tables are in different databases. I wish it was that simple :(

Comment: I missed that, sorry. But for the combination and uniq!, that would still work, isn't?

Comment: Yes, that would work. But that's not my problem. I'm an expert Rubyist, so the how to toss duplicates out of an array isn't the answer I'm looking for. I need advice on the best way to _automatically_ get the total unique count of numbers. My first thought is to just pull data from each, dump it to a file, and have another script do what you're doing above. The problem is with 500k records it's too much (too slow).

Comment: If you are tossing out duplicates, why are you using union all?

Comment: Also for different db's look at dblink or foreign data wrappers.

Answer (score 1):

For accessing the different data wrappers look into dblink and/or foreign data wrappers depending on your Pg version.

Then you can do this entirely in PostgreSQL.  Keep in mind you probably want to do something like ensuring that the two servers return only non-duplicate records.  So assuming you are using fdw's and assuming you have foreign tables pna and pnb set up, something like:

```
 WITH pnas (phone_number) AS (
      SELECT phone_number 
        FROM pna
    GROUP BY phone_number
 ),
 pnbs (phone_number) as (
      SELECT phone_number
        FROM pnb
    GROUP BY phone_number
 ), 
 pns (phone_number) AS (
      SELECT phone_number 
        FROM pnas
       UNION
      SELECT phone_number
        FROM pnbs
 )
 SELECT count(*) 
   FROM pns;
```

This of course should work with 9.1 only, but you could do something similar with dblink and PostgreSQL 8.4 and higher.

Answer (score -2):

What about this then :

```
Table1.count(:group => 'phone_number')
```

Will give you an hash of the count, and the value. Merge the 2 results together, you've got your answer.

Comment: Wait, you're the same guy that commented above. WTF?

Comment: This query does exactly what you commented above, on the database, without you having to pull all 500k records and put them in memory. It returns you a response calculated for each db. Sorry if this doesn't help you, you should have been clearer, looks like nobody else understands it, or else you would have had other answers. And thanks for the downvote for somebody trying to help you out.